# R - qplot - plot two lines from different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code to plot:

```
q <- qplot(quarterYear, var_1, data=dataset_1)
q <- q + geom_line(aes(group = 1))
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

which uses the following quarterly datasets:

```
> dataset_1$var_1
 [1]        NA        NA        NA        NA  444618.3 1556125.2  744145.1  844862.2  773188.2
[10] 1204732.2 1832308.2 1732186.6 1475089.7 1238791.2  772359.0  927111.5  982978.9  581415.1
[19]  489457.8  446419.0  403841.0  654630.9  753729.4  513755.0  587031.5  465808.7  462710.4
[28]  537923.9  409037.8  785118.7

> dataset_1$quarterYear
 [1] "2012Q1" "2012Q2" "2012Q3" "2012Q4" "2013Q1" "2013Q2" "2013Q3" "2013Q4" "2014Q1" "2014Q2"
[11] "2014Q3" "2014Q4" "2015Q1" "2015Q2" "2015Q3" "2015Q4" "2016Q1" "2016Q2" "2016Q3" "2016Q4"
[21] "2017Q1" "2017Q2" "2017Q3" "2017Q4" "2018Q1" "2018Q2" "2018Q3" "2018Q4" "2019Q1" "2019Q2"
```

I would also like to plot the following variable in the same graph from another dataset (which uses annual data instead of quarterly):

```
> dataset_2$var_2
 [1] 3544407      NA      NA      NA 5254710      NA      NA      NA 4430303      NA      NA
[12]      NA 2499437      NA      NA      NA 2216218      NA      NA      NA 2024459      NA
[23]      NA      NA 2537232      NA
```

How can I add this second line in the same graph with the first variable?

EDIT:

Here is a dataframe with all the variables needed:

```
> dput(dataframe_1)
structure(list(var_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3544407.49, NA, NA, 
NA, 5254709.85, NA, NA, NA, 4430302.745, NA, NA, NA, 2499437.24, 
NA, NA, NA, 2216217.61, NA, NA, NA, 2024459.22, NA, NA, NA, 2537232.26, 
NA), quarterYear = c("2012Q1", "2012Q2", "2012Q3", "2012Q4", 
"2013Q1", "2013Q2", "2013Q3", "2013Q4", "2014Q1", "2014Q2", "2014Q3", 
"2014Q4", "2015Q1", "2015Q2", "2015Q3", "2015Q4", "2016Q1", "2016Q2", 
"2016Q3", "2016Q4", "2017Q1", "2017Q2", "2017Q3", "2017Q4", "2018Q1", 
"2018Q2", "2018Q3", "2018Q4", "2019Q1", "2019Q2"), var_2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 444618.290581211, 1556125.2312821, 744145.122633215, 
844862.245210837, 773188.163309878, 1204732.23940684, 1832308.19798703, 
1732186.62322613, 1475089.69403864, 1238791.22680584, 772358.984604352, 
927111.535808541, 982978.903715697, 581415.120412662, 489457.818616084, 
446419.025443493, 403840.992700758, 654630.928503824, 753729.397874631, 
513754.997587623, 587031.503365487, 465808.650890606, 462710.391792817, 
537923.914536013, 409037.838465172, 785118.681845306)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The easiest way is to combine the datasets and then plot the different variables. You have to set a matching x-axis for all your y-axis variables, before you will be able to plot them together.

Comment: Can you give me the code of what you are suggesting to do?

Comment: Only if you could provide 2 example datasets. In pseudocode it would look like:
1. Split quateryearcolumn to a quarter column and a year column
2. left join dataset2 on dataset 1 using the year column in dataset1 and dataset2
3. plot all desired lines.

Comment: I have provided the dataset above you have all you need right?

Comment: It is easier when you provide scripts which create a dataframe. People are less likely to help you when you have hardcoded dataframes. I do not want to spend my time typing over dataframes. ;)

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: I have added a dataframe, hope this is what you were asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the data! As explained in the comments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Step1 - Create a year column

```
df2 = dataframe1 %>% mutate(Year = substr(quarterYear, start = 1, stop = 4))
```

Step2 - Create column with var_1 per year, for later left_join

```
df3 = df2 %>% distinct(var_1, Year) %>% filter(!(is.na(var_1)))
```

Step3 - Left join to get data for ggplot in desired format

```
df4 = df2 %>% select(Year, quarterYear, var_2) %>% left_join(df3)
```

Step4 - Plot Data

```
ggplot(data = df4) + geom_line(aes(x = quarterYear, y = var_1, group =
                                           1)) + geom_line(aes(x = quarterYear, y = var_2, group = 2)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```